# Is it possible to dissolve Raspberry ketone in warm water?

Tags: solubility

I poured a small amount of RK in cold water and it clumped together so I warmed it in the microwave and it disappeared in the water meaning it dissolved, but i was under the assumption that RK is insoluble in water, so what happened ?

Answer (score 4):

According to PubChem, 4-(4-hydroxyphenyl)-2-butanone (Raspberry ketone) is estimated to be partially soluble in water, ca. 25.1 g/L @ 25 celcius.

[https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4-*4-Hydroxyphenyl*-2-butanone#section=Experimental-Properties](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4-_4-Hydroxyphenyl_-2-butanone#section=Experimental-Properties)

My initial thought is what would one need with Raspberry ketones? Their health effects seem to lack any clinical evidence.

Comment: The question is not about 25 °C, rather what happens with solubility at elevated temperatures, how microwave radiation affects it, and whether hydrolysis or any other reaction takes place.

Comment: @andselisk I can agree somewhat with your comment and perhaps my answer lacked a breath of information. I will remove it shortly because I haven't the time to expand upon it but wish you to see this reply.

Comment: No, it gives some useful information, it's just that it has questionable relevance. Probably leave it for now and edit later when you will have some more time.

Comment: I am not in favour of this question/answer as for the same can happen to everything if the premise are trivially wrong. OP supposed the stuff much less soluble but it turns out that at RT is already soluble for a good 25 g/l. Heating up would speed up dissolution and likely increase solubility. I didn't get why to ask in first place. The answer seems trivial  but correct.   At LigninPauling and @andselisk

Comment: @Alchimista According to [IFA's GESTIS database](http://gestis-en.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll/gestis_en/070200.xml?f=templates$fn=default.htm$3.0),  it's "Practically insoluble in water" which is in agreement with what OP said. However, what would happen after microwave treatment puzzles me as there is still no definitive answer. Besides, PubChem refers to ToxNet, ToxNet to EPA homepage for TSCA. I fail to see a solid reference for this solubility data.

Comment: @Andselisk I am just failing to see the ground for all this. Some grams per litre are enough to answer the question. If I would do what OP describes, I would rather say RK is (sparingly, readily, ecc) soluble in warm water. If RK is listed as much more insoluble than I agree. By Googling I found the same value 25. No polemic at all. Just failing see the relevance of the Q and thus of the related feedbacks.

Comment: @Alchimista Yeah, sometimes science is not about "why?", rather "why not?" It seems to be the case here:)